# Are there any security concers with using @truffle/hdwallet-provider?

Tags: truffle, security, truffle-hdwallet-provider

The project I am working on asked if I would remove the usage of @truffle/hdwallet-provider from our project due to security concerns. (One of the previous team members had supposedly concluded it isn't being updated and that it has vulnerabilities)

I was very surprised to hear this, as I know it to be a solid product with regular updates.
The latest update [@2.0.10](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider) was delivered just a few days ago.

However, I wanted to ask here, just in case I was missing something. (Can't ever be too careful about security)